How to capture text within double quotes when providing arguments
I have a tcsh script which takes arguments and then it process those argument values to be used further. Example:
test.sh -i ./inputFileForCI -alog "log comment to be captured"

How to capture entire string of "log comment to be captured" and store in a variable? With the code I have below arg3_value is log but I want "log comment to be captured"
What range options can I use to get the entire string?
set arg1_value = "" 
set arg3_value = ""

@ i = 1 

while ($i <= $#argv)
    switch ($argv[$i])
        case "-i":
        @ index = $i + 1 
        set arg1_value = $argv[$index]
        echo "arg1 value is $arg1_value"
            breaksw
    case "-alog":
            @ index = $i + 1
        set arg3_value = $argv[$index]
        echo "arg3 value is $arg3_value"
        breaksw   

        case "-h":
            echo "#----------------------------------------------------------------------------"
            echo "# -i        : Input File"
        echo "# -alog     : Comment log"
            echo "#----------------------------------------------------------------------------"            
            echo "EXAMPLE:"
            echo "test.sh -i <path_to_input_file> -alog <comment to be added>"
            echo "#----------------------------------------------------------------------------"
            exit
        default:
            echo "xyz"
            exit 1
    endsw
    @ i = $i + 2 
end

